# Using CMake with AVR Toolchain in Cygwin or MinGW

Tags: c, cygwin, mingw, avr, clion

I'm currently trying to get a toolchain setup so I can build an AVR project from CLion.

My starting point is [this](https://github.com/acristoffers/CMake-AVR), specifically, the Blink example. The issue is that it, along with existing CMake for AVR examples, are all for Linux based systems.

What I've tried is installing WinAVR to get the executables. I've modified the CMakeList.txt so the program names contain the following:

```
set(AVRCPP   "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-g++")
set(AVRC     "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-gcc")
set(AVRSTRIP "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-strip")
set(OBJCOPY  "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-objcopy")
set(OBJDUMP  "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-objdump")
set(AVRSIZE  "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-size")
set(AVRDUDE  "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avrdude")
set(AVRAS  "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-as")
```

While using the Cygwin environment, CMake has no issue finding my compilers, but when I try to build the project, avr-gcc is being passed parameters in Linux format.

```
C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-gcc.exe -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec420260872.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c /cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/2eb381d5/2eb381d5/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
avr-gcc.exe: /cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/2eb381d5/2eb381d5/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to have CMake pass avr-gcc arguments in a format it can work with?

For reference, this is the full output:

```
Error:The C compiler "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-gcc" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
 Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/2eb381d5/2eb381d5/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make.exe "cmTryCompileExec420260872/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec420260872.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec420260872.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/2eb381d5/2eb381d5/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_report /cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/2eb381d5/2eb381d5/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec420260872.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-gcc.exe -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec420260872.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj -c /cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/2eb381d5/2eb381d5/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
avr-gcc.exe: /cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/2eb381d5/2eb381d5/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c: No such file or directory
avr-gcc.exe: no input files
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec420260872.dir/build.make:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec420260872.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/2eb381d5/2eb381d5/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec420260872.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec420260872/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec420260872/fast] Error 2
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Comment: I've been struggling with setting up CMake for a hc11 toolchain. I posted my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228336/how-to-stop-cmake-appending-c-compiler-flags

Answer (score 0):

I use cmake and avr on windows and on linux. 
The syntax is the same. Why do you want to use cygwin in the mid of that?

In any case you didn't show your toolchain file.
When cross compiling using cmake you need to provide a toolchain file where you set all the configuration related to the compiler.
You need to do this because when cmake starts it try to compile a simple program and it try to run it. If you are using an avr compiler on a computer cmake can't run the executable, so it fails.

You need to put an extra care including this command in the toolchain:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
```

it is needed for skip this compilation and so to avoid the failure.

I think this is a good read where to begin:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/CmakeBuild